# jsf session timeout loop

Tags: jsf, session, exception, loops, timeout

I've a problem with JSF session handling:
At first i got everytime a `viewExpiredException`:

```
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/anyForm.jsf - View /anyForm.jsf could not be restored.
```

So I added the following code to my `web.xml` file:

```
<error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/index.jsf?reason=expired</location>
</error-page>
```

and the following in my `index.jsf` file (which also got some forms and inputs):

```
<h:outputText value="#{messages.session_expired}"
              rendered="#{param.reason == 'expired'}" />
```

whenever I get a timeout now, I am redirected to the `index.jsf` and the text is shown, **but** if I enter a value in an input and press the submit button of the form, I still get a redirect to my `index.jsf`. So, I am stuck in a loop. I also tried things like:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

due to the fact that I read `index.jsf` then automatically create a new session. However, this didn't help me at all.
I also get this exception if I got a (loop) timeout and change a value of a input and submit the form (I am using primefaces "spinner" input):

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState(AttachedObjectListHolder.java:165)
    javax.faces.component.UIInput.restoreState(UIInput.java:1411)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl$2.visit(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:276)
    com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1589)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
    javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:344)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:263)
    com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:188)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:452)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:148)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:192)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992526/how-to-handle-session-expiration-in-jsf-2-0) helps.

Comment: no, this is where i got my "solution" from. sure i could insert an meta-refresh, so i never get a timeout, but that would be a bad solution...

Comment: Have you excluded the browser cache from being the suspect? See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/3642969 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9931378