# Clicking browser back button after JSF navigation causes "Document expired" in browser

Tags: caching, jsf-2, navigation, servlet-filters, back-button

In my project after login page, main page contain menu on left hand site if I clicked on menu link 1 ==> you will navigate to page 1 then click menu link 2 ==> you will navigate to page 2 ,if you use back button then i get ***document expired***.

I want to delete the browser cache after logged out for this i use phase listener.

code of phase listener

```
    @Override
        public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
            FacesContext facesContext = event.getFacesContext();
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext
             .getExternalContext().getResponse();
        logger.log(Level.INFO,"Cache control phase listener called");
             response.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
             response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
             response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
             response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate"); 
             response.addHeader("Expires","Mon, 8 Aug 2006 10:00:00 GMT");
        }
```

I also use ***UserFilter*** for secured the pages in /user/* folder
    here is UserFilter's ***doFilter*** code

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.log(Level.INFO,"User Filter's doFilter called");
        UserManager userManager = (UserManager)((HttpServletRequest)request).getSession().getAttribute("userManager");
            if(userManager==null || !userManager.getIsLoggedIn() || !userManager.getCurrentRole().equals("user")){
                String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getContextPath();
                ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect(contextPath+"/login.xhtml");
            }else{
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
    }
```

I also want after login user can't go back again in login page until logout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *if you use back button then i get "document expired"*

That will happen if the previous request was a synchronous POST request (a form submit). You're not supposed to use POST for page-to-page navigation. Use GET for it.

In other words, replace `<h:commandLink/Button>` representing pure page-to-page navigation links/buttons by `<h:link/button>`. And, when you need to navigate to a new page after a form submit, e.g. to display a list after submit of an entry, use POST-redirect-GET.

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one/15523045#15523045)
- [Is JSF 2.0 View Scope back-button safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930900/is-jsf-2-0-view-scope-back-button-safe/)
- [Avoid back button on JSF web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305718/avoid-back-button-on-jsf-web-application)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: a `PhaseListener` is the wrong tool for the job of manipulating HTTP response headers. Use a normal `Filter`.