# Allow back button support for Viewscoped beans in JSF2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean, cache-control, view-scope

In my application i have multiple viewscoped beans  when someone click back button in the browser it gives error for obvious reasons,my bean is destroyed when i move away from the page.
**I want** to allow user to go back to previous page.
Cache is enabled in the browser but still it doesn't do that.

Is there anything i can setup in my application to allow that?

Comment: You mean to say, disabling the browser cache isnt an option? (it is the answer!) Anyway ... Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930900/is-jsf-2-0-view-scope-back-button-safe

Comment: I tired adding <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD </param-name>
  <param-value>client</param-value>
 </context-param> but still doesn't work!. Is there any way to go back keeping beans scope to view scoped??