# Converting from Seam to weld CDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, seam, cdi, weld

I am converting a project from Seam to CDI and I am quite new in these fields. I am stuck in converting  @Startup, @Cretae, @RequestParameter , @Out , @AutoCreate ,@ Destroy
 tags, what is the alternative for these tags in Weld CDI?

Answer (score 1):

There's an `@Startup` EJB annotation and the `@PostConstruct` annotation that map to what you're looking for. Have you seen the migration bit on jdf http://www.jboss.org/jdf/migrations/seam2/open18_migration/ ?

Comment: Thank you , that was a very useful link. It solved some of my problems :)

Comment: Do you have any idea about the replacement for @Out and RequestParameter. Can we outject in Weld?

Comment: No, there is no outjection. Use Producers. RequestParams are not in there either. Might be a worthwhile extension to write.

Comment: If you want to inject request parameters and use JSF2 you could take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239975/depedency-inject-request-parameter-with-cdi-and-jsf2

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use `@Disposes` in your CDI objects to destroy a produced object,  `@PreDestroy` would do it if it's an auto created bean whereas `@Disposes` destroys an object created by `@Produces`.    `@Produces` is the rough equivalent of `@Out`.

`@RequestParameter` can be brought in via Solder Servlet, no direct equivalent in CDI directly.

Answer (score 1):

Check this automated Seam to CDI conversion application:

https://github.com/jharting/classic