# @ManagedProperty with request parameter not set in a @Named bean

Tags: jsf, cdi, managed-bean, http-request-parameters, managed-property

I've a CDI managed bean wherein I'd like to set request parameters as managed properties:

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ActivationBean implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.key}")
    private String key;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.id}")
    private Long id;

    // Getters+setters
```

The URL is `domain/activate.jsf?key=98664defdb2a4f46a527043c451c3fcd&id=5`, however the properties are never set and remain `null`.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

I am aware that I can manually grab them from `ExternalContext` as below:

```
Long id = Long.parseLong(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id"), 10);
String key = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("key");
```

However, I'd rather use injection.

Comment: have you tried to change RequestScoped on ViewScoped?

Comment: CDI doesn't provide out-of-the-box request parameter injection (and you can't use what you have because JSF won't inject into a CDI context, although the reverse is possible). Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239975/depedency-inject-request-parameter-with-cdi-and-jsf2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `@ManagedProperty` on a CDI managed bean works only when you're using JSF 2.3 or newer. You'll then need the `@ManagedProperty` annotation from [`jakarta.faces.annotation`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/faces/annotation/managedproperty)/[`javax.faces.annotation`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/annotation/managedproperty) package instead of the `javax.faces.bean` one, and you need to use it in combination with `@Inject`.

```java
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.annotation.ManagedProperty;
// Use jakarta.* when you're already on JSF/Faces 3.0 or newer

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ActivationBean {

    @Inject @ManagedProperty("#{param.key}")
    private String key;

    @Inject @ManagedProperty("#{param.id}")
    private Long id;
```

The `@ManagedProperty` annotation from the [`javax.faces.bean`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/bean/managedproperty) package works only in beans annotated with the legacy `@ManagedBean` annotation and has been deprecated since JSF 2.3 and removed since Faces 4.0.

In case you're still on JSF 2.2, or you just happen to already use the JSF utility library [OmniFaces](https://omnifaces.org), then you can also use its [`@Param`](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/Param) annotation instead. It automatically infers the parameter name and type from the Java field, hereby further reducing the boilerplate.

```java
@Inject @Param
private String key;

@Inject @Param
private Long id;
```

Alternatively, you can also use the [`<f:viewParam>`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/vdldoc/f/viewparam) tag in the view for the purpose.

```xml
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="key" value="#{bean.key}" />
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.id}" />
</f:metadata>
```

#### See also

- [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id)
- [How do I process GET query string URL parameters in backing bean on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724428/how-do-i-process-get-query-string-url-parameters-in-backing-bean-on-page-load)
- [Backing beans (@ManagedBean) or CDI Beans (@Named)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named)

Answer (score 0):

The question and the accepted answer are very old.  Nowadays, with Jakarta Server Faces, you can use [`@ManagedProperty`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/faces/annotation/managedproperty) with `@Inject` in a `@Named` bean:

```java
@Inject @ManagedProperty("#{param.key}")
private String key;
```