# How can I get URL parameters in JSF

Tags: jsf-2

I can get the URL or URI just fine. However, JSF seems to exclude any URL parameters. For example:

**Suppose the url is:**  *www.example.com/pleasework?param=1*

```
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

 public String getUrl() {
   HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) 
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
   String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
   String uri = request.getRequestURI();
   return uri;
 }
```

My result is everything up until the `?` but I need everything after the `?`

How can I accomplish this in JSF

**Note**: I need to get the URL server side so using Javascript's `window.location.href` and storing value in hidden field is not a solution for me because I need the parameters on page load.

Comment: Try the [`getParameterMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap()) method on the `request` object. Or you can also use the `getParameter(parmName)` method.

Comment: @BheshGurung  Yeah, not sure how I missed this. Thanks/sorry. Write as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: Way more easy solutions. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28780051/managedproperty-with-request-parameter-not-set-in-a-named-bean

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for the contribution; however I believe that the solution you're referencing applies to `@RequestScope` bean. My bean is `@SessionScoped` and this would not be a solution for me, but perhaps will be for someone else.

Comment: `@Named` with `@Param` works in sessionscoped beans as well (you did not mention SessionScoped) And for 'page load' there are other solutions too where it is explicit in the page that it is for pageloading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id where the @Param has additional features for validation etc... Cool thing!

Comment: This job is meant to be done by the JSF framework..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`getParameterMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap()) method on the `request` object. Or you can also use the `getParameter(parmName)` method.