# JSF 2.2 inject Deltaspike (CDI) windowId into Bean

Tags: jsf, cdi, jsf-2.2, wildfly-10, deltaspike

I'm currently using JSF 2.2 with Deltaspike. We use the Multi-Window-Handling from Deltaspike to handle separate windows. It works great but in a specific case, we need the window ID.

I am able to read it with:
`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("dswid");`

Is there a more elegant way, maybe with injection into my bean?

Regards,

Sebastian

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Depedency inject request parameter with CDI and JSF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239975/depedency-inject-request-parameter-with-cdi-and-jsf2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Param](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/Param) from OmniFaces. I find it more elegant, but it is a third libary.

```
@Inject @Param
private String dswid;
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Deltaspike and omnifaces should be part of a jsf project at all times

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add a library, you can also inject the external context.

@Inject
private ExternalContext externalContext;

Comment: Without dependency on a different framework AND with real injection of the param, not just the context, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239975/depedency-inject-request-parameter-with-cdi-and-jsf2 and Deltaspike and OmniFaces should be part of a jsf project at all times ;-)