# JSF / CDI error: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type String with qualifiers @Default

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf, cdi, inject

I am doing basic exercises while learning JSF 2.2 with CDI annotation, running on Tomcat 9. The error log is here:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/JSF2]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/JSF2]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type String with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private com.faire.jsf.tutorial.ConditionalNavigation.pageId
  at com.faire.jsf.tutorial.ConditionalNavigation.pageId(ConditionalNavigation.java:0)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:378)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:290)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:143)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:526)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am running a .xhtml page with this code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<f:commandLink action="#{conditionalNavigation.showPage}" value="Redirect to Convert page">
    <f:param name="pageId" value="convert"></f:param>
</f:commandLink>

</body>
</html>
```

And this .java class:

```
package com.faire.jsf.tutorial;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ConditionalNavigation {

    @Inject             
    private String pageId;

    public String getPageId() {
        return pageId;
    }

    public void setPageId(String pageId) {
        this.pageId = pageId;
    }

    public String showPage() {
        if (pageId == "convert") {
            return "convertNumberDate";
        } else {
            return "conditionalnavigation";
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to google / search stackoverflow but to no avail - I do not understand what is the error pointig out. Is the @Default pointing to .xhtml page injecting parameter without qualifier? What mistake am I making?

Comment: The CDI implementation does not know what to @Inject to your field `pageId`. `@Inject private SomeType someField;` requires that there's exectly one bean of `SomeType` present that can be injected to `someField`. `String` is quite generic here without additional hint via annotation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Selaron! That makes sense. I know that it can be done with @ManagedPropertyvalue(= "#{param.pageId}"), but I have been unable to find the equivalent with CDI. Is there any annotation I could use? If not, what would be the "propper" way?

Comment: This might help: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/Param  (Omnifaces annotation). Found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239975/depedency-inject-request-parameter-with-cdi-and-jsf2#13239977

Comment: Ok, I see - the correct solution is either to use an existing library, or write custom annotation. Thanks for pointing me in right direction! 

On another note - how can I marked the question as answered?

Comment: As there is no answer yet, you can't simply mark it answered. But you can write an answer yourself explaining the root cause of the exception and suggesting solutions (or even presenting your working tested solution) and finally mark it as the answer. If soneone later researches for exact that exception, your solution will be found quickly. Answered questions get high priority in search results for good reason :-)